# How do I set an ENV variable equal to a file path?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables

I'm currently trying to use the google-auth-library to generate a token to be used in my request to a Google Cloud Function but it errors out and asks me to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to a service account credentials JSON file.

I tried just creating the env variable like any other in my .env.local file and assigning it the relative path to the JSON file (ex. "../credentials.json") however that didn't seem to work. I'm just wondering what the correct way to point to this file is so that it will work both in development and production? Thanks!

EDIT

I've added some more details about my project below as recommended by John Hanley's comment.

- Language: Javascript
- Framework: NextJS

The code that is trying to use the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable is in the 'google-auth-library' library which I am trying to use in the following endpoint. This endpoint is in the `pages/api` folder.

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
const { GoogleAuth } = require('google-auth-library');

export default async function handler(
req: NextApiRequest, 
res: NextApiResponse
){
  let data: any;
  const auth = new GoogleAuth();
  const targetAudience = 'cloud_function_url';
  const url = targetAudience;

  async function RequestToken(){
    console.info(`request ${url} with target audience ${targetAudience}`);
    const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience);
    const res = await client.request({ url });
    console.info(res.data);
    data = res.data;
  }

  RequestToken().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error.message);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  });

  res.status(200).json({ data });
}
```

When I call this endpoint, I get the following error:

```
Cannot fetch ID token in this environment, use GCE or set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to a service account credentials JSON file.
```

Comment: 1) Use an absolution path and not a local path. 2) the usage of `.env.local` depends on the language and framework. Edit your post with details and show the code that accesses `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

Comment: Which type of credentials are in the JSON file? It should contain `"type": "service_account"`. What are you running the code on? Have you setup authorization via the CLI `gcloud`. It appears that credentials are being detected but they are the wrong type.

Comment: The `"type":` is "authorized_user". The code is just running on a development server, but for production would be hosted on Vercel. I did create the funciton via the gcloud in the cli and I did not include the --allow-unauthorized tag when deploying it so that it would require authentication.

Would I need to create a service account for my application and generate a default_credentials file for that account?

Comment: You are using the wrong type of credentials. Those are not from a service account. Follow the documentation to create and download a service account JSON key file. The SDK is able to process the service account JSON key file directly. You do not need to setup the CLI `gcloud` to use that service account. You can do that if you want but it is not required for the SDK code.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll refer back to the documentation to hopefully set everything up properly this time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks again for the help! I went back and created a service account and I got it working, however, I'm curious how this is going to work in a production environment? Currently I just hard coded the absolute path into the .env variable but I'm sure the production environment won't have the same exact path right?

Comment: If your code is running in Cloud Functions, then you can use the Metadata service to get credentials. That support is built into the SDK libraries. Do not set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and the SDK will automatically fetch credentials from the default service account attached to your function.